# Merge two mp3 files through ffmpeg in android not working

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to merge (overlap) two mp3 files in one output file through ffmpeg but I'm receiving the below log messages, I guess a syntax error which I'm not able to identify.

I'm using this external library to interact with ffmpeg: github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

**Command executed**: `ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/bass.mp3 -i /storage/emulated/0/clap.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 /storage/emulated/0/output.mp3`

(the paths are obtained with getabsolutepath)

**Messages taken from log**:

> ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
>
> built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>
> Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/bass.mp3':
>
> [mp3 @ 0xb5886400] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
>
> [NULL @ 0xb5887000] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
>
> ffmpeg: Invalid argument

Comment: Can we get the code where you execute this command and can you try this command with adb shell from your computer?

Comment: I'm using this external library to interact with ffmpeg: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java I'm not sure how to execute adb code from my windows laptop...? BTW thanks for answering and advising

Comment: No you won't be able

Comment: Please update the question and add that you are using this library.

Comment: Updated! Thanks for your advises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo, your problem is reported in the issues and it is [here](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/43): you just do not have to type ffmpeg at the beginning of the command.

Comment: I've tried now your solution and now I have a different error message,so it looks you were ok, many thanks! Now I receive message "unknown encoder libmp3lame" Have you seen this before in Android? Remember I'm using the library I wrote in the comment before. If you have any idea don't worry, I'll check on the web.

Comment: Thanks, the pity is that the link of the binary they are providing is not existing :( I'm starting to think that implementing library "ffmpeg-android-java" was not a good idea for my need of working with mp3 files.

Comment: Ok, I do not precisely know, never heard about this library before but it sounds like it is ok: >300 stars (btw, if it solved your answer, validate the answer, it avoids others to see as unsolved)